# python-hashlib-md5 how can i decode this file?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, md5, hashlib

I have managed to get an input from the user and then encrypt it using md5 and md5 hex digest but I cant figure out a good way of decoding this code can anyone help?

```
username = input("Please enter your username")
passwd = input("Please enter your username")
for line in open("test.txt","r").readlines(): # Read the lines
    line = (str(hash_object.hexdigest()))
    login_info = line.split()# Split on the space, and store the results in a list of two strings
    #needs to decode login info so that it is not encoded
    if username == login_info[0] and passwd == login_info[1]:
        print("Login allowed")
    else:
        print("inccorect")
```

Comment: it sounds like you are asking how to reverse the effect of applying a hash function like md5. hash functions are explicitly designed *not* to be easy to invert. https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2019/01/24/reversing-an-md5-hash/

Comment: thanks for the help really appreciate it.